# ContactPicker's pickContactAsync is not working properly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, contactpicker

i'developing an application that has feature to select a contact from Contacts list.

Problem is, when i run application in "DEBUG" mode and debug my ContactPicker code, the picker runs quite thouroughly.

but when i run application in the device without debugging by simply delpoying it and choose option to "Select from Contact List" the app suddenly crashes and "Start screen" appears directly.

Anyone know what is this problem?

Here's snippet of my code::

```cs
private async Task SelectContacts()
{
  try
  {
       ContactPicker contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
       contactPicker.desiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.append(ContactFieldType.PhoneNumber);

       Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();

    if (contact != null)
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        ...
        ...
        ...
        //my next implementation
    }
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago and I couldn't figure out what the problem was. Though I found a solution for my situation, I can't guarantee it will work for you.

So, if you don't have much code written besides this contact picker, I suggest recreating the project, or creating a new one, and adding the contact picker code first, before anything else.
That is what I did, and then added the rest of my code and it worked. There was no exception thrown in my app, the contact picker just crashed the app after half second inactivity or just simple scrolling in the contact list. So, the contact picker appeared and then crashed.

Hope this helps.